# Experiencing slow internet speed on my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, atheros, mobile-broadband, download-speed

I have dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 in my laptop with mobile hotspot internet connection. I am experiencing  slow internet speed on both Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 as well. Likewise, if on my mobile net speed 100 KB/s then on my laptop net speed is ~50 KB/s. In fact net speed gets almost half on my laptop. To fix it, I tried this,

```
sundar@sd1:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for sundar: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 6c:2b:59:43:f8:0f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2204000-d2204fff memory:d2200000-d2203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 28:3a:4d:5a:b6:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-74-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.43.252 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:d2000000-d21fffff
```

But, it didn't worked.

Anyone, please help me to resolved this ASAP.